# Trick when dynamically appending GET attributes

Tags: url, web, get

When dynamically building SQL queries you often see something like this:

```
WHEN 1=1 AND title="Example" AND ...
```

The purpose of the 1=1 is to be able to keep appending AND-statements without having to check if any previous statements exist. Thereby avoiding something like this happening:

```
WHEN AND title="Example" AND ...
```

I quite often come across a related issue when building the the attributes/search-query for a GET request. I don't want to keep checking if I need to prepend the attribute with '?' or '&'.

So my question is, is there any 'safe' way for me to add an initial attribute that won't interfere with any potential software on the server side. Assuming I do not have full knowledge of the backend.
Something like:

```
http://example.com?1=1&title=example
http://example.com?null&title=example
http://example.com?i-am-useless&title=example
```

Or is this allowed?

```
http://example.com?&title=example
```

Is there perhaps a simpler way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure the URI-string you want to add parameters to already ends in a '?'. Then for every key-value pair, add 'key=value&' to it. Optionally you can then in the end delete the last character from the resulting string. - Reddit user omepiet